What is the Galois Group of $(x^8 - 1)(x^2 + 2)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?
I am studying for some algebra qualifying exams over the summer and I am stumped on the title question: What's the Galois Group for $(x^8 - 1)(x^2 + 2)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?
Here's what I've got so far:
$p(x) = (x^8 - 1)(x^2 + 2) = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)(x^2+2)$
Now, I don't think the $(x-1)(x+1)$ factors matter at all, so I'm ignoring them. The other factors are irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, $(x^2+1)$ clearly has root $\pm i$ and $(x^2+2)$ has roots $\pm \sqrt{2}$. Then $(x^4+1)$ has roots equal to the 4th roots of unity, which are equal to $\sqrt{\pm i} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)$ and thus all roots of the polynomial $p(x)$ lie in the field $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{2})$ and so that's our splitting field.
Individually, I believe I know the Galois group of the individual irreducible factors. For instance, (I think) the Galois Group of both $(x^2+1)$ and $(x^2+2)$ to be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as they're both degree 2 extensions with automorphisms given by conjugation.
Similarly, the Galois group of the factor $(x^4+1)$ is isomorphic to the group $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ which is easily to be seen $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
Now, after some reading and looking at other related questions, I have learned that if $G_1, G_2$ are Galois groups for polynomials $p_1(x), p_2(x)$ respectively then $G_1 \times G_2$ is not necessarily the Galois group of $q(x) = p_1(x)p_2(x)$, (there seem to be some conditions where this is true, but I don't understand them) and with that said, I have no idea how to find the Galois group of the polynomial $p(x)$. At this point I'm lost and I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that I have multiple irreducible factors.

The Galois group of a reducible polynomial is the Galois group of its splitting field. So you only need to pay attention to $\mathbb{Q}(i, \sqrt{2})$.

That makes sense. In this case that is just $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ correct?

Yes, that's right. You made a small sign error which turns out not to matter: the roots of $x^2 + 2$ are $\pm \sqrt{-2} = \pm i \sqrt{2}$, but since $i$ is also in the splitting field either $\sqrt{2}$ or $\sqrt{-2}$ can be used to define the splitting field.
